# Date after number of days in lua scripting

Tags: date, datetime, lua, lua-scripting-library

I am new to lua scripting. I have a startDate (`"03-05-2014"` as `"dd-mm-yyyy"`) and a span in days (`2`) Can anyone help me how to get the `endDate` based on the `startDate` and `span`?.

```
Example startDate     span            endDate 
        ---------     ----            -------
        03-05-2014     2             05-05-2014
       (dd-mm-yyyy)                 (dd-mm-2014)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you

```
local dayValue, monthValue, yearValue = string.match('31-05-2014', '(%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d%d%d)')
dayValue, monthValue, yearValue = tonumber(dayValue), tonumber(monthValue), tonumber(yearValue)
now = os.time{year = yearValue, month = monthValue, day = dayValue}
numberOfDays = now + 2 * 24 * 3600
print(os.date("%c",numberOfDays))
dateAfterNumberOfDays = os.date("%a %d %B %Y, %H%p%M",numberOfDays)
print ("\nafter number of days "..dateAfterNumberOfDays) -- give you date after number of days
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do any math here. `os.time` and `os.date` will do it for you.

```
local day, month, year = ("03-05-2014"):match("(%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d%d%d)")
local span = 64
local endtime = os.time({day = day + span, month = month, year = year})
print(os.date("%c", endtime))
```

Comment: and if the days roll over to the next month?

Comment: @LukeAllison I assume the answer was written in such a way to communicate that overflow is not an issue (since `span=64` will always overflow)

Comment: Can confirm above ^. It properly rounds to the next month.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the whole program for you, but here's something you can start with:

1. Get the day, month and year from the string:

   ```
   local day, month, year = string.match('03-05-2014', '(%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d%d%d)')
   day, month, year = tonumber(day), tonumber(month), tonumber(year)
   ```
2. Use [`os.time`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.time) to get the timestamp of a start time. You can
   then add `3600 * 24 * 2` seconds (2 days) to get the timestamp of the end time.
3. Use [`os.date`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date) to formats the string from a timestamp.

Comment: first: `os.time` depends on your operating system and might not give you a value in seconds. Second: `3600 * 24 * 2` is not guaranteed to be exactly two days. There might be issues with winter savings time and certain leap years which change the length of a day every so slightly